# How to force Groovy Script Engine to output compiled classes in files?

Tags: groovy, compilation, classloader

I googled and found out you can make GroovyScriptEngine output scriptCache into class files by setting setTargetDirectory. But when I execute the code something like below from scala, it doesn't generate class files.

How do you set GroovyScriptEngine to output class files from scripts compiled by GroovyScriptEngine?

```
var gse = new GroovyScriptEngine()
gse.getConfig().setTargetDirectory("c:/test")
var scriptClass = gse.loadScriptByName("SomeGroovyClass.groovy")
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you cache a compiled class made by Groovy Script Engine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10151791/how-do-you-cache-a-compiled-class-made-by-groovy-script-engine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `GroovyScriptEngine` does not seem ([from looking at the source](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/groovy/util/GroovyScriptEngine.java)) to use that property of `CompilerConfiguration`

It would need to be passed in the constructor of the inner `ScriptClassLoader`, so that the `GroovyClassLoader` that it extends gets the configuration when it is constructed.

Comment: @Elonoa You could always submit this as a RFE to the [Groovy JIRA](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY)? Or even better, come up with a patch/pull request?